# Where do we exactly draw the line on a question, being off-topic?

Tags: discussion

This morning, I ran into [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867838/where-can-i-share-my-custom-scripts) on code-sharing options. Reading through the answers, I very much liked the (at this moment highest voted) very nice overview by Serg.

The question mentioned OP wanted to share his custom scripts, ***written for Ubuntu***. We may therefore assume OP is looking for Ubuntu-related sharing options.

The answer by Serg was accordingly; at least http://paste.ubuntu.com/, https://launchpad.net, and  http://askubuntu.com are specifically Ubuntu related, while the others can also be used for other purposes, but perfectly fit in, since they can *also* be used for Ubuntu-related code.

In the Help- section we find a.o.:

> **Questions that you may ask:**
> ..........
>
> ```
> Development on Ubuntu.
> ```

In the section:

> **Questions that you should avoid:**

I don't see specific information why this question should be off-topic, so my question:

Why do we consider this question off-topic?

Comment: I was not sure whether this question should be closed or not, when I saw it. In relation to the help centre quote, I guess the logic would be, how to share a script (that happens to be about Ubuntu) is relevant to, but not the same thing as, development on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Zanna yeah, I can imagine you would consider it off-topic at first sight, but I don't think it is. Practically all I wrote as an application started with a script. Options to share it are essential I think. I actually loved the question, and so Serg's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Of the sites mentioned, Ask Ubuntu itself is not a site for sharing scripts. Let's make that clear first - a lot of answers involve scripts, but sharing scripts for general use is not the intention here.

Having got that out of the way, it doesn't matter at all where or for what purpose the scripts were created when it comes to sharing - the pastebin, Github and its various alternatives, even Launchpad - they can all be used irrespective of the the distro. That the script is for Ubuntu doesn't make one bit of difference.

Lastly, my own close reason was actually the too broad one - this isn't the place for a big list of code sharing sites. Simply for that reason, I'd think this question would offtopic anywhere on SE.

Comment: I follow you, but that options, mentioned related to Ubuntu, should be off-topic *because* they can also be used for other distros was never an argument here as far as I know. Practically 100% of the cli answers here can also be used on any other Linux distribution. The too broad was the first thing that popped into my mind, reading the question, but in practice, I don't think it turned out to be *that* broad.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I'm not saying the answers make the question offtopic - my point is that saying the script is for Ubuntu doesn't make any difference when it comes to sharing.

Comment: @JacobVlijm of course it is too broad - Serg hid a whole bunch of sites under the Github point and the pastebin point, and they all could be legitimate answers.

Comment: ...Not if you focus on what may be assumed as Ubuntu-related, and where we may assume other Ubuntu users may look, which both Q and A did.

Comment: @JacobVlijm oh? How does that limit the number of answers in any way?

Comment: The same would count for any cli answer.

Comment: First, Ask Ubuntu is very well suitable for sharing scripts, as long as it is wrapped in a proper (possibly self-answered) Q&A. Second, many questions here are not exclusively specific to Ubuntu, most would work for other Linux distributions and some about applications maybe even on Windows as well. This does not make them off-topic though. I must admit that I also more or less agree with the "too broad" close reason, because it mainly asks for a list of things. I'm glad that Serg managed to post his great answer before it got closed, but I'm not sure whether I would want it it be reopened.

Comment: @ByteCommander of course, that's why users here have Github and Launchpad repos for their scripts. Please, AU and SE sites are good for code snippets.

Comment: @JacobVlijm the same could count for almost any answer (not just CLI) - but in practice you and I know that there only a few reasonable solutions - but all of those code sharing sites are reasonable solutions.

Comment: Reasonable, but not obvious. I think the highest voted answer mentioned the obvious ones, which makes a useful (short) list on this site imo.

Comment: @JacobVlijm obvious or not, makes no difference to me. FWIW, I upvoted both the Q&A, and as far as I am concerned, it doesn't belong anywhere on SE.